# Asterisk 11 not transcoding

Tags: sip, asterisk, codec

I have defined an ip address / domain in sip.conf and defined it in a way that I forced the call to come on g729

Now I reloaded the asterisk after exiting sip.conf by saving it

and called the number by making thu debug on .. expecting the call to be on g729 but the call comes only on pcmu or pcma (ulaw / alaw)

any ideas?

my sip.conf

```
[IP]
host = IP
type = peer
port = 8060
disallow = all
allow = g729
canreinvite = no
```

Answer (score 0):

Very likly it use other section.

Do following:

```
asterisk -r
core set verbose 5
sip set debug on
```

and check output.